# Rebasing onto an older commit

Tags: git

I have three commits:

```
* d868098 Three
* 865eb70 Two
* 6dd085d One
```

And I want to move 'Three' directly onto 'One':

```
* 865eb70 Two
|
| * d868098 Three
|/
* 6dd085d One
```

However, nothing I'm trying is working.  For example, `git rebase --onto 6dd0 865e d868` simply rewinds HEAD but doesn't rebase anything.  How can I achieve this using `rebase`?

---

Update: Okay, `git rebase --onto 6dd0 865e d868` *does* work. It wasn't working for me before because I was trying this on a test repository that had only empty commits. As soon as I created meaningful commits, everything worked as expected. I will avoid empty commits for testing in the future!

Comment: Your rebase command looks correct. There must be something else going on. Does the rebase complete successfully, or did it perhaps stop because there were conflicts? Show us the output of the command.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. This was not working because I was testing on a repository that had only empty commits. I have updated the OP now.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you need at least 2 branches.

I assume you are on `master` branch which refers to `* d868098 Three`.

1. `git reset --hard 865eb70` (remove `* d868098 Three` from `master`)
2. `git checkout -b three_brach` (create and move to new branch)
3. `git checkout 6dd085d`
4. `git cherry-pick d868098` (pick `* d868098 Three` to `three_branch` branch)

Now the tree is below

```
* 865eb70 Two (master)
|
| * d868098 Three (three_branch)
|/
* 6dd085d One
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can achieve this with `git cherry-pick`. However, I want to know how to do this with `git rebase`, because I might need to move more than one commit. And, also, I want to learn everything about rebasing.

Comment: OK, If commits of Three part is much more than Two part, using `git rebase -i` and removing Tow part in opened editor is easier.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this with `git rebase --onto`, though? I don't see why the command I mention in the OP doesn't work. Regards

Comment: onto also works. As I said, you need a branch. Please try `git rebase --onto 6dd0 865e master` (Fix branch name). I guess this is what you want.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It just moves 'master' to point to the first commit. Nothing actually gets rebased.

Comment: Sorry, it does work. The only reason it wasn't working on my end was that I was using a test repository with empty commits. The empty commits change Git's behavior a lot here! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Yeah, I know. Very initial repo is a bit tricky.